# I am not getting the video played in this code. It is showing me just the video compoment but video is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Sidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu, useProSidebar } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
import { List,Database,PersonWorkspace} from 'react-bootstrap-icons';
import Plyr from 'plyr-react';


function PortSwiggerAcademy() {
  const { collapseSidebar } = useProSidebar();
  const [selectedLink, setSelectedLink] = useState('');

  const Sqllinks=[
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLrZMCRvP8Y&t=3s',
        'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/dLnsxK4gndY',
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/jF-L_h_5c68',
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/zrp9H4ZTHcU',
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/q2KuGi4UO1w',
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/eWm2u9w6bRQ'
  ];

  const handleLinkClick = (link) => {
    setSelectedLink(link);
  };

  return (
    <div id="app" style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%'}}>
      <Sidebar style={{backgroundColor:'dark'}}>
        <Menu iconShape="square">
          <MenuItem icon={<List/>} onClick={() => collapseSidebar()}>Home</MenuItem>
          <SubMenu label="SQL-Injection" icon={<Database/>}>
            {Sqllinks.map((link, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} onClick={() => handleLinkClick(link)}>
                SQL {index + 1}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </SubMenu>
          
        </Menu>
      </Sidebar>
      <div style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'column',margin:'0 auto'}}>
        <h1>Protswigger Series</h1>
        <h2>Note: Hard labs are solved in Courses</h2>
        <h3>Click a video to play</h3>
        {selectedLink && <Plyr source={{ type: 'video', sources: [{ src: selectedLink }] }} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PortSwiggerAcademy;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The video should be render properly according to the links but it the video is not gettig properly. I am trying to get the youtube video and using plyr.io to display the video the code is just showing the video content but the is not getting played.